# Prevent dialog from showing in EditTextPreference onClick

Tags: android, preferences, accountpicker

I want to show the system dialog from which the user can pick his google account, and I want it to show when the user click in an EditTextPreference. The problem is that the "normal" dialog keep showing before the system default one.

Here is the code.

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    Preference googleMail;
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
            new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE},
            true, null, null, null, null);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        PreferenceCategory fakeHeader;

        // Add 'fake' preferences.
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_fake);

        fakeHeader = new PreferenceCategory(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        fakeHeader.setTitle(R.string.pref_header_calendar);
        getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(fakeHeader);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_calendar);

        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("pref_googleMail"));

        googleMail = findPreference("pref_googleMail");
        googleMail.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, ACCOUNT_PICKED);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your EditTextPreference to plain Preference. After this basic dialog is not shown.